# Symfony transformer always getting a null value

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem using the following `CallBackTransformer`:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder
        ->create('codes', 'hidden')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($codesCollection) {
                if (!$codesCollection) {
                    return "{}"; // This is always returned
                }

                return implode(",", $codeCollection->toArray());
            },
            function ($codesString) {
                return $codesString;
            }
        ))
    )
);
```

The `codes` property of the entity for which this form is used is a many-to-many relation, and in the case I'm testing I've checked that the value is set as expected.

The reverse transform callback recieves the expected string ( `$codeString` ), however the transform callback recieves `null` as its parameter every time. I expect this to be the `ArrayCollection` I get when calling `getCodes` on the entity.

What could I be doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it turned out to be was that there was a `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` that was attached to the field, and even though it did not modify the value(s) at all, it resulted in the value being null in the transformer. I changed my event to be `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA`, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Data transformers are used to translate **the data** for a field into a format that can be displayed in a form (and back on submit). The first transforms the **original value** into a format that'll be used to render the field.

So, **"the data"** and **"original value"** refers to the initial value of this field from underlying object. To see a different result you need put a default value to `codes` field (if it doesn't already comes from DB for instance). Otherwise it will always be `null`.

Comment: >  To see a different result you need put a default value to codes field (if it doesn't already comes from DB for instance).

The case is, though, that I expect it to get the value from the database, where `codes` is a many-to-many relation which I've confirmed that actually holds data. Therefore I expect that data (an `ArrayCollection` of the related entities) to be passed to the transform callback. Am I mistaken in expecting that to be the case?

Comment: I think you should show us this part then, where you invokes to this form type.